# how to open a file using strings of other file in python?

Tags: python

I have 1000 files, and the name of these are "numbers", for example, 2323.csv.
I have these name in a file called 1.txt. 
Now I want to open these files one by one in python, using 1.txt to open them.

How can I do this?

Comment: sample of 1.txt file:        2323   \n  2425   \n   2748.    So it has one column consists of names of files (without .csv, but it is very easy to add .csv at the end of them in the case of need)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this?

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as listFile:
    for line in listFile:
        with open(line.rstrip(), 'r') as individualFile:
            # do stuff
```

Comment: I would add `with open(line.rstrip(), 'r') as individualFile:` if each filename is on a line

Comment: how can I use  "data = pd.read_csv('line.csv')", where "line" is the lines of 1.txt?

Comment: @Ares, the point is that with this method, I cannot put a name to the column.For example I usually use this: data = pd.read_csv('1.csv',names=["k0","k1","k2","k3","k4"]).   How can I add name to each column by with open(...) ?

Comment: @ReihanehKouhi I think what you're looking for in this case is a csvreader then: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @Ares :  thanks. I use data = pd.read_csv(line.rstrip(),names=["k0","k1","k2","k3","k4","k5"])  and it works! :)  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Roughly and very basic but understandable code (no error handling).

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():  # This assumes each line has a number
     with open('.'.join([line, 'csv']) as cf:
         file_content = cf.readlines()
         print(file_content)
```

Comment: You don't need to read the file into a list with `f.readlines`, you can loop directly over `f`. But either way, you need to get rid of the `\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, you are right. Good catch, it's being too long I don't use python this way.

Comment: how can I use "data = pd.read_csv('line.csv')", where "line" is the lines of 1.txt?